# Query with multiple joins across multiple tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have tables in my database in PostgreSQL as shown in following picture[image: tables]

All columns in orange are integers and primary keys of their respective tables.
All columns in pink are foreign keys; the arrows denote which foreign key links to which primary key.

I want to get a result containing `Track.title`, `Artist.name`, `Album.title` and `Genre.name`, by joining on the following conditions:

```
Track.album_id = Album.album_id
Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id
Album.artist_id = Artist.artist_id
```

But I am unable to get the required results.
I have tried the following queries so far, all of them with errors:

1.

```
select Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name from
Track inner join Genre on Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id
inner join Album on Track.album_id = Album.album_id,
Album inner join Artist on Album.artist_id = Artist.artist_id;

ERROR:  table name "album" specified more than once
```

2.

```
select Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name from
Artist, Track inner join Genre on Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id
inner join Album on Track.album_id = Album.album_id AND Artist.artist_id = Album.artist_id;

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "artist"
LINE 3: ...join Album on Track.album_id = Album.album_id AND Artist.art...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "artist", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

3.

```
select Track.title,Artist.name,Album.title,Genre.name from Track join Genre join Artist join Album
on Track.genre_id = Genre.genre_id and
Track.album_id = Genre.album_id and
artist.artist_id = album.artist_id ;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 4: artist.artist_id = album.artist_id ;
```

These queries are all giving me errors and I'm not able to get the required output. Please help me to get those 4 columns with proper join

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097)

Comment: I flagged your comments as no longer needed, but if a moderator then deleted them, they agreed. PS You tried 3 things & gave up & then asked us to write your code without giving all the DDL it used or setting up an example or showing that  what you gave actually had those problems, etc etc. That is not appropriate. Ask 1 question about 1 piece of buggy code with a [mre] and explain how you are stuck, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You have `,` and `album` before `inner join` in the last line of your first query

```
select 
  t.title, 
  ar.name, 
  a.title, 
  g.name 
from Track t
inner join Genre g
on t.genre_id = g.genre_id

inner join Album a
on t.album_id = a.album_id

inner join Artist ar
on a.artist_id = ar.artist_id;
```